# Multiplying Array.length returns NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I'm a newbie in JavaScript, can someone explain to me why I'm getting `NaN` as output from this code?

```js
var car = new Array("Honda", "Toyota", "BMW", "Merc");
var calc = 3 * car.legth;

alert(calc);
```

Comment: You spelled `length` wrong. `car.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `3 * car.length;` as `car` is an array and it has `length` property to return the number of elements in the array.

```js
var car = new Array("Honda", "Toyota", "BMW", "Merc");
var calc = 3 * car.length;
alert(calc);
```

Comment: omg......simple typing error, :)  this is why problem solving skills is important in any programming language?  thx bro